# Storing objects in object array with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongoose, mean-stack

I am trying to push several comment objects into my UserSchema in mongoose. However, whenever I run this code, it only creates the "_id" fields for each comment entry, i.e. [image: example]

```
function saveUser(user) {
  user.save(function (err) {
    if (err)
      console.log(err);
  });
}

function createUser(req, res, callback) {
    var userData = new User({username: req.params.username});

    getUserComment(req, res, function(testComment) {
        userData.comments.push({body: testComment});
        saveUser(userData);
    });
}
```

My schemas:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var CommentSchema = new Schema({
    comments: {
            score: Number,
            body: String
            }
});

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: {type: String, unique: true},
    comments: [CommentSchema]
}, { collection: 'user'});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Of course, I have more properties but I just included a snippet to show that even one small example does not work.

Answer (score 0):

There was an extra "comments" in the call because of how I declared the CommentSchema. Painfully obvious now!